# How to load font from resource using dwrite API?

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts, directwrite

I want to load a font from a compiled resource which is the program itself.  I can load it using AddFontMemResourceEx when I was using GDI.  However, direct 2D has it own Dwrite API which is not compatible with GDI.  The [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/appendix--win32-migration) suggests using `CreateCustomFontFileReference` + `CreateCustomFontCollection`.  Could anyone give me an example how to do it?

Comment: A bit of googling: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/DirectWriteCustomFontSets

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks for helping, don’t you think the example is too overkill?  Could you write a function just “Install the resource font to system”?

Comment: The `AddFontMemResourceEx` function, if used properly, will effectively install the font for the duration of the executable that calls it. That is to say, if that function is successful, you can use the font *as though it were* installed.

Comment: @AdrianMole I just tried it.  It does not work with dwrite.  I successfully got the handle.  But I can not use the font in TextFomat struct.  It still used the default one.

Comment: This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/custom-font-sets-win10) describes various ways in which you can use custom fonts in your app. Or on earlier Windows versions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/custom-font-collections

Comment: Another way is to use IDWriteInMemoryFontFileLoader, but that probably requires recent Windows releases. If you need it to work with Windows 7+ you'll have to go with a custom loader.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the DirectWriteCustomFontSets sample in the microsoft/windows-classic-samples repo on GitHub ([here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/DirectWriteCustomFontSets)). It demonstrates five scenarios using a custom font set, and based on your question it sounds like case 4 would apply to your situation: "Creates a custom font set using font data contained in in-memory buffers."

For this scenario, the key interface is [IDWriteInMemoryFontFileLoader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/Mt807692(v=VS.85).aspx), which was added in the Windows 10 Creators Update (spring 2017).

The specific files in the sample project that will be most relevant are:

- CustomFontSetManager.h/.cpp — this includes members applicable to the other scenarios as well
- BinaryResources.h/.cpp
- Document.h/.cpp — this is described as simulating a document file containing the font data (e.g., a .doc file), but it could be any kind of binary.